# Why does Windows 7 recognize my second monitor yet the second monitor remains blank?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dvi, vga, crt

I bought a **new monitor** (Acer X203H) and wanted to plug it into my graphics card but on my graphics card one plug says **CRT** which is already filled with the first monitor and the second says **DVI**, which I don't have a cable for on my second monitor.

[image]

I found what looked like a **VGA** outlet on my **motherboard** and plugged it in:

[image]

My **Windows 7** recognizes the monitor and my **mouse** goes beyond my first monitor apparently onto the second monitor but my second monitor **remains blank** and when I turn it off and on it says **no signal**.

[image]

**How can I get my second monitor to work? Do I need to get an adapter or a cable to plug it into my graphics card instead of the VGA port?**

## More info based on answers:

I've also read in [some reviews](http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/847925) that the Acer X203H is supposed to have DVI support, but here is a picture of the back of my monitor where I plug in the cable, it looks like there is a place for a DVI cable but this particular model doesn't have one. Ergo, I think my best bet is to get a VGA-to-DVI converter as Will suggested.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you only connect the DVI?

Comment: @harrymc I don't know because I don't have a DVI cable or adapter at the moment as Will suggested below. I guess the solution is to buy a VGA-to-DVI converter and plug my second monitor into the DVI slot on my graphics card.

Comment: Or you could buy a DVI cable alternatively. It'll likely be more expensive than the $2 adapter I listed, but assuming your monitor supports DVI, you should get a (slightly) better image and you could find the cable at any local computer store.

Comment: @Will, by "DVI cable" I assume you mean a VGA-to-DVI cable, right? Since as the last picture above shows, the monitor seems to have a physical area for a DVI out port to be, but mine doesn't seem to have this out port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a video card, so the VGA port on your motherboard is disabled. I wouldn't expect the monitor plugged into the motherboard to be recognized even, but I suppose it's possible.

I'd recommending connecting to your monitor using the video card's DVI slot (the white port next to the VGA connection). If your monitor does not support DVI, you can plug a [DVI -> VGA converter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041903&p_id=2396&seq=1&format=2) into the slot.

DVI usually provides a higher-quality connection, so you should plug your new monitor in the DVI slot if possible, and your older, CRT monitor, into the nearby VGA slot.

Comment: +1: Most motherboards won't allow you to use on board and a video card at the same time. Your best solution is to use DVI as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the specs the Acer X203H does have DVI, a quick look should confirm that. In that case the best solution would be a DVI-DVI cable.

The second option would be a DVI-VGA connector, but first verify that your Graphics Card supports 2xVGA. The DVI ports come in different flavors, analog VGA being an option. From the picture I would say you're OK, but a DVI cable is the safer bet.

And Acer is being cheap, not including a 2nd cable. Did you check the box again?